# How does Rebus work with Azure Service Bus topics?

Tags: rebus

I'm new to Rebus and Azure Service Bus and would like to understand how Rebus works with Azure Service Bus topics and queues.

I've managed to successfully get Rebus to work with ASB but am a bit puzzled as to what's going on under the covers.

I have an ASP.NET Core application that configures Rebus as follows:

```
services.AddRebus(configure => configure
    .Logging(l => l.Serilog())
    .Transport(t =>
        {
            switch (messagingConfig)
            {
                case MessagingConfig.RabbitMq:
                    t.UseRabbitMqAsOneWayClient(messagingConnectionString);
                    break;
                case MessagingConfig.AzureServiceBus:
                    t.UseAzureServiceBusAsOneWayClient(messagingConnectionString);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        })
    .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().Map<BaseMessage>("publisher"))
);
```

I also have a console application that subscribes to the messages, configured as follows:

```
using (var activator = new BuiltinHandlerActivator())
{
    activator.Register(() => new Handler());

    Configure.With(activator)
        .Logging(l => l.ColoredConsole(minLevel: LogLevel.Warn))
        .Transport(t =>
        {
            switch (BusConfig)
            {
                case MessagingConfig.RabbitMq:
                    t.UseRabbitMq(RabbitMqConnectionString, "consumer");
                    break;
                case MessagingConfig.AzureServiceBus:
                    t.UseAzureServiceBus(AzureServiceBusConnectionString, "subscriber");
                    break;
            }
        })
        .Start();

    Console.WriteLine($"Listening for messages on {BusConfig}...");
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit");

    activator.Bus.Subscribe<AdditionalSessionRequestMessage>().Wait();
    activator.Bus.Subscribe<AcceptInvoiceMessage>().Wait();

    Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Quitting...");
}
```

When I look in the Azure Portal, I see a topic created for each of my message subclasses (I have two) and I see a queue created called "subscriber".

From what I can surmise it would seem that I can just configure a service bus in Azure Portal and the Rebus will create topics as needed for each of the message types. Similarly, the subscribing application will create an input queue as needed.

I'd just like to verify that my understanding is correct.

Comment: Your understanding is correct :) you can read more here: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Azure-Service-Bus-transport